# OSGi FrameworkListener & BundleListener doesn't work

Tags: java, osgi

I've created spring bean, implemented BundleContextAware, and subscribed for FrameworkEvents and BundleEvents but don't receive any callbacks. What I'm missing?

```
public class MyBean implements BundleContextAware, BundleListener, FrameworkListener {

    @Override
    public void setBundleContext(BundleContext bundleContext) {
        this.bundleContext = bundleContext;
        log.info("setBundleContext");
        bundleContext.addFrameworkListener(this);
        bundleContext.addBundleListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void bundleChanged(BundleEvent event) {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void frameworkEvent(FrameworkEvent event) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: It's implemented correctly, but I am not sure about Sprint DM that I am assuming you are using. I bet that `setBundleContext` is not called and that is occuring outside your class so you should look at how you have configured your Sprint context.

Comment: I've intentionally added logging to that setter, and I can see record in log file. This is what I'm so confused at..

Comment: How did you deteremine that you don't get any events? Did you stop/start a bundle? Note that you only get the events that occur after the listener registration occur, which may be after all bundles are in the started state.